# View / Edit / Delete options missing in Project Web Apps in Project Server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, project-server

I have a strange behavior during trying to edit PWA instance in Central Administration !

[image]

any help I will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this error before where this problem might occur because of one of the following reasons :

1. You don’t have  elevated permissions to manage PWA instance via the current user.
2. In some cases,you might need to add the central administration site to intranet zone.
3. The farm requires updating to at least July CU 2015.

I checked this View, [Edit, Delete options are missing within Manage Project Web Apps in Project Server](http://blog.devoworx.net/2016/06/25/view-edit-delete-options-are-missing-within-manage-project-web-apps-in-project-server/) that helped me to solve this issue,Hope this help you.